# Can cassandra be installed in Local host?

Tags: database, installation, cassandra

I want to learn Cassandra. Can the database be installed in a desktop or a laptop. Please let me know?
I also want to know the minimum system requirements for installing cassandra.

Answer (score 2):

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraHardware

Its java, you should be able to run it just about anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm

It is a tool written in python that can start a multi-node test cluster for playing around on your laptop.